# Need to use instance in static and non-static methods

Tags: c#, methods, instance

I'm making a little text game. The starting dialogue is in my main (static) method. From there, it sends you to other methods depending on your choices.

Now I think I need to have an instance of my class for this to work.

For example:

```
Program p = new Program();

if(stuff){
    p.room1();
}
else{
    p.room2();
}
```

Within those other methods there are global variables that will change.

So above the main method there is:

```
public bool hasItem = false;
```

So room1() would look like,

```
public void room1(){
    if(stuff){
        p.hasItem = true;
    } 
}
```

I know I'm screwing something up with the main method. Do I declare the instance "p" inside or outside of the main method? I've tried both but get errors both ways.

Edit: I ended up declaring a static "Program" outside of the main method to use elsewhere. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am not following your question at all.  Is the issue is that you don't know where to declare `hasItem`?  I would suggest you declare it as a member variable of the object that represents the thing (room, world, player, whatever) that actually *has* the *item*.

Comment: I thought that's what I did by declaring it outside of a method. Is that not the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you can either create a static `Program` outside of your main method, or declare a program inside your main method, depending on your architecture.

Second, you don't have to reference your instance from within your instance methods.  Just use the field name. like so:

```
public void room1(){
    if(stuff){
        hasItem = true;
    } 
}
```

you can use `this.hasItem` if you want to be explicit about it.

---

Or better yet, make a brand new class to keep your state in.  Having instance members in the class with the main method is awkward design.